# How to reduce the size of node_modules folder

Tags: npm, angular

I have done Angular 2 application using npm, when the app has just 1 mb size, the node_modules folder consumes around 90 mb,so Is there any possibility to reduce the node_modules folder size, at least while publishing in IIS?

Comment: You do not need to publish the `node_modules` folder. Instead do `npm install` after deploying your code.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest using [grunt-package-minifier](https://github.com/salsita/grunt-package-minifier)

Initially I strip all the package.json, README etc. from node_modules but keep the essential JavaScript files in a structure that can be used by a CommonJS module loader.

Also have a look at [reduce-node-modules-bloat.md](https://gist.github.com/greim/e8e1bd3b1ed08a7505ce)

Hope this helps